# How to test if an address is readable in linux userspace app

Tags: linux, memory, segmentation-fault, memory-address

For debugging purposes I need to test a pointer to see if it points to a valid readable page. Currently I am parsing /proc/[pid]/maps to see if the address is mapped ok, but this seems a bit long-winded. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: I'm doing it parsing `/proc/self/maps` as well

Comment: @GregoryPakosz: For that to be a generic & reliable solution, wouldn't it require reloading and reparsing the map on every check to account for things like a growing heap or newly mapped-in memory segments?

Comment: @etherice: No because /proc is self-refreshing; every time you access a /proc file(s), kernel code runs that regenerates it's "content".

Comment: @etherice I believe that is correct.

Any solution to this will be fundamentally unreliable in the presence of parallelism, interrupts or faulty hardware. There is a time-of-check to time-of-use race window ([CWE-367](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html)). The memory pointed to by the address can be unmapped, protected or poisoned between checking the address and using it.

Comment: check this article: https://renatocunha.com/2015/12/msync-pointer-validity/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The canonical way is to use the `write()` system call to read from the page (writing to a dummy `pipe()` file descriptor).  Instead of faulting, it will return `-1` with `errno == EFAULT` if the buffer passed to `write()` is unreadable.

Comment: Warning: Have seen at least one other SO solution suggest using /dev/null for this purpose (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611776/isbadreadptr-analogue-on-unix), but newer kernels (I tested on 3.8.7) return success for /dev/null write() even if 'buf' is NULL. So while this test might work with /dev/null on whichever system you're testing on, it's definitely not a portable solution. Using some other fd (like a dummy pipe or posix shm object) would not be as fast but it would definitely be safer and more portable.