# segmentation fault handler crashes with segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, arm

I am using arm machine and segmentation handler sometimes crashes while obtaining crash context address:

```
void crit_err_hdlr(int sig_num, siginfo_t * info, void * ucontext)
{
 uintptr_t fault_address = NULL;
 struct sigcontext *ctx = &(((ucontext_t*)ucontext)->uc_mcontext);
 fault_address = ctx->arm_pc;

 //after reading ctx->arm_pc it crashes
}
```

This is how handler is setup:

```
struct sigaction sigact = { 0 };
sigact.sa_sigaction = crit_err_hdlr;
sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO |  SA_RESTART;
if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigact, (struct sigaction *)NULL) != 0)
{
 //error, bail out
}
```

Is there any possible way to check if arm_pc filed in sigcontext is readable, so I can avoid the crash in crash handler?

Comment: Handling `SIGSEGV` is critical, as more or less everything of the process's memory management might already be trashed, in the moment the handler is called.

Comment: What OS are you talking about?  Linux, Posix, etc.? See [isbadreadptr on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611776/isbadreadptr-analogue-on-unix) or [IsBadReadPtr search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IsBadReadptr+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the memory corruption performing operations inside the handler